# Fast user switching with Devise and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I followed this article to create fast user switching in Devise:

http://pivotallabs.com/users/mbarinek/blog/articles/1387-fast-user-switching-with-devise

What I don't understand is that in the cucumber file, it says

```
"And I follow the "Sign in as" link for user: "bob"".
```

But there is no sign_in_as_path when I run rake routes.

I'm using activeadmin, and when I try to generate the Admin/users view with the addiitional "sign in as" field:

```
  column "Sign In As" do |user|
      link_to "Sign in As", :controller => "signinas", :action => "create"
  end
```

and this in routes:

```
  match "/admin/signinas/create"   => "SignInAs#create"
```

It gives me this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant SignInAsController::SignInAs):
  app/controllers/sign_in_as_controller.rb:2:in `<class:SignInAsController>'
  app/controllers/sign_in_as_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I don't know how to trigger the create action in the SignInAsController, specified in the article, from admin/users.rb, which contains this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
    column :email
    column :name
          column "Sign In As" do |user|
      link_to "Sign in As", :controller => "signinas", :action => "create"
  end
  end
end
```

thanks for response

Comment: I updated question. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I resolved this. I will update with solution shortly if my resolution indeed works fine.